# How to pass outputs from two different lists to consecutive process in next flow

Tags: groovy, nextflow

Say I have two processes.

```
Channel
    .fromFilePairs("${params.dir}/{SPB_50k_exome_seq,FE_50k_exome_seq}.{bed,bim,fam}",size:3) {
        file -> file.baseName
    }
    .filter { key, files -> key in params.pops }
    .set { plink_data }

process pling_1 {
    publishDir "${params.outputDir}/filtered"

    input:
    set pop, file(pl_files) from plink_data

    output:
    file "${pop}_filtered.{bed,fam,bim}" into pling1_results

    script:
    output_file = "${pop}_filtered"
    base        = pl_files[0].baseName

     """
        plink2 \
        --bfile $pop \
        --hwe 0.00001 \
        --make-bed \
        --out ${output_file} \
     """
}
process pling_2 {
    publishDir "${params.outputDir}/filtered_vcf"

    input:
    set file(bed), file(bim), file(fam) from pling1_results.collect()
    file(fam1) from fam_for_plink2

    output:
    file("${base}.vcf.gz") into pling2_results

    script:

    base          = bed.baseName
    output_file   = "${base}"

     """
     plink2 \
     --bfile $base \
     --keep-fam ${params.fam}/50k_exome_seq_filtered_for_VEP_ID.txt \
     --recode vcf-iid bgz --out ${output_file}
     """
}
```

The result of pling_1 process is two list of elements,

```
[/work/SPB_50k_exome_seq.bed, /work/SPB_50k_exome_seq.bim,/work/SPB_50k_exome_seq.fam]
[/work/FE_50k_exome_seq.bed, /work/FE_50k_exome_seq.bim,/work/FE_50k_exome_seq.fam]
```

Therefore, in the `ping_2` is not I am not able to process `SPB_50k_exome_seq` and `FE_50k_exome_seq` in one go. The `base = bed.baseName` is only taking `SPB_50k_exome_seq` and omitting `FE_50k_exome_seq` from the second list. In this case, how can I pass both `SPB_50k_exome_seq` and `FE_50k_exome_seq` to the `pling_2` process?

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experiments, I found the solution. Would help someone who is looking for solutions.

The reason for the problem was the process `pling_1` produces so many files as output, all of which are outputted into the same channel. Therefore, you need to break up and re-group those files into a tuple of the format.
For that, I used the following channel where you can use operators like `combine` & `flatten`.

```
pling1_results
    .collect()
   .flatten()
    .map { file -> tuple(file.baseName, file)}
    .groupTuple(by: 0)
    .map { input -> tuple(input[0], input[1][0], input[1][1], input[1][2])}
    .set { pl1 }
```

Then use the channel `pl1` as input for the next process. In addition to that, you should pass all the items through the channel into the process as a single input. Like the following,

```
set val(pop1),file(bed), file(bim), file(fam),file(fam1) from pl1.combine(fam_for_plink2)
```

With these two changes, now the workflow is running for each sample/input in the tuple.instead for just one.
Thanks

Comment: when is `flatten()` needed? or when to decide flatten to use?